# How to pass reference to abstract class - Java

Tags: java, reference, abstract

```
Data data = new Data("path"); //I read data from excel and save. This code is in Main.

public abstract class Generator{
   public abstract double[][] generate();
   //here I need reference - data
   }

public class GeneratorA extends Generator{
   public double[][] generate(){
   //first implementation - I want to work with data
   }
}


public class GeneratorB extends Generator{
   public double[][] generate(){
   //second implementation - I want to work with data
   }
}
```

What I need is passing reference (data) to abstract class Generator. I can pass reference in constructors of GeneratorA/GeneratorB but I have more child classes and it is inefficient. Is any way how to pass reference data to abstr. class Generator? I just want to inherit reference from class Generator...
Thanks!

Comment: If the generate method needs the `Data data` object you should pass it as an argument.

Comment: hmmm I thought I could read `data` from parent class somehow...

Comment: Alternatively you can implement a `setter` in the parent class which stores the `data` in a field of the parent class. You then need to call that setter though before calling your `generate()` method ...

Comment: Are those non-static inner classes? If so you should be able to read `data` if it is a field in the parent class. But I agree with Peter in that it would be better to just pass `data` to `generate()`.

Comment: Make changes: `public abstract double[][] generate(argument);` You could inherit this method and pass the desired variable/reference (data-whatever you call it).

Comment: because if I want pass it as an argument I have to pass it in construtor of child class... or not? What I want is pass reference only once and not to every class.

Comment: You must add a constructor to your abstract class. Then you just have to call `super(data)` in subclasses constructor.

Comment: thank you all, I think it will be useful

Comment: P.S java is pass by value, not reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a constructor to your abstract class. Then you just have to call `super(data)` in subclasses constructor.

See the code bellow:

```
public abstract class Generator{

    Data data;

    public Generator(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public abstract double[][] generate();
        //here I need reference - data
    }
}

public class GeneratorA extends Generator{

    public GeneratorA(Data data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public double[][] generate(){
        //first implementation - I want to work with data
    }
}


public class GeneratorB extends Generator{

    public GeneratorB(Data data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public double[][] generate(){
    //second implementation - I want to work with data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can have non-abstract methods and constructors.

```
public abstract class Generator{
   Generator(....)
{
   //set here
}
   public abstract double[][] generate();
   //here I need reference - data
   }
```

You could use the constructor to set the values in the subclass.

OR

If for some reason you don't want to add a constructor/non-abstract method to the abstract class `Generator` ,you could add one more class which extends `Generator` and the other subclasses could extend this new class.

You could write a method in the new class for setting values and use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your description you need the same data reference in all Generator objects in this case you can store data as a static field in the abstract class and access in objects of sub classes like:

```
public abstract class Generator{

    static Data data;
    public static void setData(Data data){
        Generator.data=data;
    }
    public abstract double[][] generate();
}


Data data = new Data("path");
Generator.setData(data);

public class GeneratorA extends Generator{
    public double[][] generate(){
        //here you can work with data..
    }
}
```