# UML Relationship between Customer and Product List (Java Supermaket Software)

Tags: java, class, uml, relationship, class-relationship

I am trying to create a supermarket software that allows either a customer or the owner to log-in and use my system via a swing based GUI in Java. When the Customer has logged in they can view products. When the owner has logged in they can view products and add new products.

I want a method in the `Customer` class: `ViewProducts()`
and methods in the `Owner` class: `ViewProducts()`, `AddProducts()`.
Are these methods wrong because they're not specific to the customer/owner (they're related to the product).

My relationship would be the `Customer` class having a 1 to 1 relationship with `ProductList` and the `Owner` having a 1 to 1 relationship with `ProductList`, and the two classes can manipulate the data in their own way. Am I going about this wrong?

This way doesn't make sense because `Customer` and `Owner` can't have attributes that aren't related to them such as `ProductList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always aim to capture what exists in reality.  A `Customer` instance *does not* have a 1 to 1 relationship with a `ProductList` because a `ProductList` can be viewed by more than one `Customer` at a time, and the `Customer` in no way *owns* that list.

What is probably closer to reality is:

- Every `Supermarket` individual *manages* one `Inventory` individual
- Every `Inventory` individual:

  - *is managed by* one `Supermarket` individual
  - *comprises* `Inventory Item` individuals
- Every `Inventory Item` individual

  - *is comprised by* one `Inventory` individual
  - *describes* `Product` individuals
- Every `Product` individual

  - *is described by* one `Inventory Item` individual
  - *is located at* one `Physical Location` individual
- Every `User Account` individual

  - *identifies* one Person individual
  - *plays* Role individuals
- Every Role individual *provides* Capability individuals

In real life, people play *roles*. These roles might be “customer”, “doctor”, or “police officer”. Every individual `Role` has a set of capabilities it can perform. In an OO system, every individual `Role` can use operations to implement its capabilities, such as `purchaseProduct()`, `prescribeMedication()`, or `writeMovingViolation()`.

There are multiple ways to represent these roles and capabilities in an OO system. In one approach, a `customer` instance of a `Role` might be configured to allow access to `queryInventory()` and `purchaseProduct()` operations on the `Supermarket` and `InventoryItem` classes respectively. An `owner` instance of a `Role` <sup>1</sup> might be configured to allow access to `addInventoryItem()` and `removeInventoryItem()` operations on the `Inventory` class.

Here is an example of a UML model:

[image]

In another approach, you might create singleton subclasses of the `Role` class, called `CustomerRole` and `OwnerRole`, and then have each of those subclasses invoke operations. You might put your `viewProducts()` and `addProducts()` operations into those singletons.

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider calling this role “manager”, so the owner of the supermarket can hire other people to do the work.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the <<use>> relations to operations are not UML compliant. If so, could you make a reference, please?

Comment: On hand I have the UML 2.5 spec. See §7.7.3.2. "A Usage is a Dependency in which one NamedElement requires another NamedElement (or set of NamedElements) for its full implementation or operation." Both `InstanceSpecification` and `Operation` are kinds of `NamedElement`. Thus, what I drew is UML compliant.

Comment: Yes, somehow ;-) The issue is, that there is no documentation for the notation of the latter. EA invented some notation and here I have another one.

Comment: Anyway, it's a good answer, but probably you should make an annotation about that notation (or find a real reference...).

Comment: Huh? See §7.7.4: "A Usage is shown as a Dependency with a «use» keyword attached to it." Perhaps EA is not as standards conformant as you think.

Comment: No. They are not referring operations/attributes but elements. Your image uses an arrow going inside the element with a little circle. EA uses an open rectangle. Both notations are inventions of the product designers (I did not say that EA is conformant; it's at about 99% or so at a guess).

Comment: A UML `Operation` _is_ a kind of `Element`. It is true that the little circle is non-standard, but why does that matter? The `InstanceSpecification` clearly depends on the `Operation`, which is exactly what you will find in the UML meta-model instances.

Comment: Yeah i agree with what you've there although program is really supposed to have users interacting with the supermarket. (Theres no backend, so the user interacts with the same place as the productList and userList). I think for this case i just have to simplify it until i implement it further.

Comment: Users _do_ interact with a supermarket -- through a role they play. For an analogy, a person flies a plane while playing the role of a pilot. Pilots fly planes. Customers shop at a supermarket. Not all users are customers.

Comment: BTW, not separating roles properly is a _huge_ source of user dissatisfaction and maintenance problems.

Comment: @JimL. Well, everything matters. Even (or especially) shortcomings of a "standard".

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to consider is the IS-A vs HAS-A. If your class is a specfic thing, it should be a child of a super class. If it has something, then it is a composition. If I were designing this, I would make productList a class and then have store employee as the super class with owner and worker as sub-classes both taking the product list as a composition. [Describes Logic of Designing Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162714/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-relationship-and-has-a-relationship-in-java)

Comment: That's what i've done. I probably didn't explain it properly my User super class and my productList class are going to be linked together somehow. Is this allowed though. Could you further justify why this relationship is allowed because in my opinion the User cannot have a productList because the products don't belong the user??

Comment: For the User super class, it could take an accessor method getProductList() to get access to the data. While there is not a strong relationship between the two classes, one could just access the data as a method for the UML. I don't think compostion/aggregration of classes would be right here.

Comment: So you would make the ProductList private inside of the generic User class?? Then the get function returns it which can be accessed by the Customer/Owner? Rather than making ProductList protected inside of User superclass. Still is this allowed because surley user still runs independantly from ProductList or is it different for abstract classes??

Comment: I would make productList its own class with a constructor and assessor methods. Then have the User class take the accessor method from productList. It should be able to access the protected data, but it should have a class relationship.

Comment: Right so my issue is that productList upon instantiation loads from a text file a load of data populating an array called products which contains many different products. If i don't have it as an attribute somewhere it's not going to populate my arrayList in productList and then im going to have to load from the file each time i want to access my data. Do you follow? (Probably should have mentioned this above)

Comment: I think I follow, I would suggest then to use an abstract class to pass the information from the product list without damaging the logical relationships. You might also think about implementing an infereace from productList. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036913/how-to-pass-reference-to-abstract-class-java

Comment: So add it the User class? (Again something i didn't think to mention when i asked the question initially) the GUI connects to a class called UserList which is an abstract class that contains a bunch of users stored in an polymorphic attribute called Users of type Arraylist<User>, so each user will generate a new array for ProductList will it not?

Comment: If you are already using an abstract class, then you might want to consider implementing an interface within the User super class. It ideally should be an abstract class, but with limitations in Java I don't think that is permissible. The only issue with using an interface is that there would be no state, so all variables would be really constants. You would need another way to update the data.

Comment: `ProductList` is an association class, not a plain one.